# Objective C: Sharing pdf files to Microsoft teams fails when using iPad

Tags: objective-c, microsoft-teams

[image: I get a success if i don't include the pdf so i assume that the pdf is the cause of the issue. I can share via onedrive, mail, and air drop in the app. Microsoft Teams returns this window after it tries to send:]

The code i use to present the action to the user after the share button is tapped, is as follows:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

if ( [activityVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ) {
            // iOS8
            [activityVC.popoverPresentationController setPermittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight];
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = [self.myUiBarButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
        }

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Sharing files has worked in the past but now has stopped working on iPad when sending pdf content to Microsoft Teams. I get the expected behaviour on iPhone though.

Both devices have IOS version of 16.4.1

The file size is the same on both devices so it is very mysterious why this only fails on one of the devices.

I know that the popover presentation controller must not be nil on iPad's and i have verified that not to be the case.

I tried adding a completion handler to my UIActivityViewController but this returned no errors.

tl;dr:
Works on iPhone, not iPad
file size is same
I don't get errors returned from the activity controller
I get error above when sending pdf to Microsoft Teams

I tried putting a pdf file into the bundle because i thought it might have something to do with memory(Busted).

I tried saving the file when didFinishNavigation gets called and then loading it when the share button is tapped because i thought it might have something to do with completion and or asynchronous issues(Busted).

I tried setting the modal presentation style and setting the preferred content size(Was not the issue).

I tried sending my url as data instead.

I tried using a UIDocumentInteractionController instead, same error.

Comment: On the iPad, can you share the file to other apps/activities without issue? Is the problem only when sharing to Teams? Is the same version the Teams app installed on the iPhone and iPad? Is the same version of iOS on both devices?

Comment: @HangarRash, both devices are on 16.4.1. I am able to use mail, air drop and one drive without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a pdf from the ipad via a native share(opened the file on device and sent it via teams), results in the same error that my app gets.

Solution, wait for ios or teams to fix this issue